# CSS: Prevent parent element getting :active pseudoclass when child element is clicked

Tags: html, css

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s0at4w4b/)**

When you click the `button`, you see that `:active` pseudoclass is triggered for the parent `div`. Is there a *pure CSS* (or some JS library) way of `:active` pseudoclass not toggling on `button` click?

I tried `z-index`, `position: absolute & fixed` and no success.

Comment: What's the objective here? does the parent ever need to be `:active`?

Comment: @Amit the objective is that I don't want the ``div`` be getting ``:active`` class on it's child click.

Comment: Yes, I got that... do you want it to be active at any other event? otherwise, just remove this rule

Comment: @RobertMcKee how ``tabindex`` wil help here? o_O

Comment: @Amit this is a simplified example. I got a lot of stuff in the real version. ``div``  has it's own ``:active`` states that should not be triggered on it's children click.

Comment: Sorry, tabindex doesn't work, my bad. The thought was that it would keep it from being activated (the button), but that only works for focus.

Comment: How about not having the child element being a child element, and instead being a sibling (or generally unrelated), but positioned "in the right place"?

Comment: @RobertMcKee Nice idea. :active and tabindex are both related to focus… Thanks to your idea I thought about `pointer-events: none|auto` but no luck. div is clicked through but clicking on a descendant will still get it active [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s0at4w4b/5/)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#useraction-pseudos):

> Selectors doesn't define if the parent of an element that is ‘:active’ or ‘:hover’ is also in that state.

That means it's implementation dependent. If an implementation chose to act this way (as current browsers obviously do), there's nothing in the standard that can change that.

With CSS4, you might be able to do:

```
.parent:active:not(:has(:active)) {
   color: red;
}
```

but that is neither available nor finalized yet.

Comment: Or simply override div:active class with standard style. In this way div element active don't change. Not very elegant but works.

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to solve this with CSS *only*:

If your button is `active`, add a `:before`-pseudo-element and with `position: absolute;` give the :before the **same** background as the parents.

```
button:active::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #eee;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Now all that is needed is that the parent is :

```
position: relative;
z-index: 0;
```

Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/s0at4w4b/4/

This does **not** solve the underlying issue, but is a solution for your current problem.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think `:has` pseudo-class will ever be available in stylesheets. If browsers finally decide to implement it, it will probably be only for JS APIs like `querySelector`.

However, I have much more hopes for [`:focus-within`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#the-focus-within-pseudo), which seems much simpler to implement.

```css
#parent:active:not(:focus-within) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Of course, it will only prevent `:active` from being applied to `#parent` when clicking a focusable element like a button. You can make other elements focusable by adding `tabindex = "-1"`

Sadly, `:focus-within` is not widely supported, but you can use a [JS polyfill](https://gist.github.com/aFarkas/a7e0d85450f323d5e164).

```css
#parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
#parent:active:not(.focus-within) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aFarkas/a7e0d85450f323d5e164/raw/"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <button>Click me</button>
  <p tabindex="-1">Or me</p>
</div>
```

Github does not allow hotlinking, so the snippet above might not work unless you copy the polyfill to your server and use it.

Comment: Hello from 2024, where we have `:has` selector 

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the simplest way of achieving what you probably *really* want to do is to put not put the button inside the `div` you don't want activated.

Here, you have a container `div`, which contains a background `div` (the equivalent of the parent `div` in your original example). The background `div` has an active state separate from the button's.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.background:active {
  background-color: red;
}
button {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <button>Click me!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution I think.

Comment: I really love your solution!

Answer (score 3):

This may or may not work for you, but this is how I achieve it with pure CSS. The only caveat is the dependence of `focus-within` which isn't supported by IE or Edge.

```
.parent {
  transition: background-color;
}
.parent:active:not(:focus-within) {
  background-color: red;      
  transition-delay: 1ms; // Delay one cycle to allow child to focus 
}
```

What's going on here is, the parent element will get the active state, as will the child that gets clicked. The only difference is that the focus will apply to the child element, but **only on the next cycle**. To circumvent any animations from while in this 2 step process, apply a 1ms delay. The next cycle, the element will be active, but the focus will be applied to the child. Thus, the parent will not apply the transition. I would imagine `animation delay: 1ms` would work the same way.

Another alternative is to give the item a `tabindex=-1` attribute and use

```
.parent {
  transition: background-color;
}
.parent:active:focus {
  background-color: red;      
}
```

The only issue with this is the fact it may change keyboard navigation behavior and relies on some HTML as well. If you do want keyboard navigation use `tabindex=0` or any value besides `-1`. But there's no JS used.

There are some nice polyfills for `focus-within` that you can use for IE/Edge but that would go outside "CSS Only".

But, we can put both of them together to create this:

```
.parent {
  transition: background-color;
}

.parent[tabindex]:active:focus {
  background-color: red;
}

.parent:active:not(:focus):not(:focus-within) {
  background-color: red;
  transition-delay: 1ms;
}
```

This works on IE11, Edge, and Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/s0at4w4b/42/

Answer (score 0):

here's a jquery solution instead of using the css pseudo class `:active`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').mousedown(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.log('i got clicked');
    });

    $('div').mousedown(function(e){
        $('div').css('background', 'red')
    }).mouseup(function(e){
        $('div').css('background', '#eee')
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function(e){
        $('div').css('background', '#eee')
    });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button>Qlick me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. But your JS logics is very narrowed to certain styles. I currently have ~20 different elements with different styles each containing about ~30 elements within with a whole bunch of different css properties. Applying your technique is terribly time-taking. When I was referring to the JS approach I was hoping for more abstract and distant approach.

Comment: what if i made a more generalized version? like click said element with classA and dont trigger active on parent element with classB so that all you had to do was add classA and classB to elements and switch your `:active` css selector to `activated`? would that suit your purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `div:active {...}` you should code `div:active:not(:hover) {...}` and the `background-color` stays untouched.

(old snippet removed)

**UPDATE**

To keep the main `div` behaviour intact and a more generic approach I usually create several layers.

Check the snippet below, toggling to `green` is just to prove that it works while `position` and `abolute` are just quick and dirty for now:

```css
#layer-data {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#layer-data:active {
  background-color: red
}
#layer-btns:active {
  background-color: green
}
#layer-btns {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 5px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto
}
#layer-data {
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px
}
```

```html
<div id="layer-btns">
  <button>Qlick me</button>
  <br/>
  <button>Qlick me too</button>
  <br/>
  <button>Qlick me three</button>
</div>

<div id="layer-data">
  some data-layer
</div>
```

Comment: This way, the div itself also loses ``:active`` effect, but it shouldn't.

Comment: Argh, overlooked that. Please give a few style examples from the list you have. I am thinking of a JS like 'toggleStyleList(arList, arValues)' or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the the active state will bubble up. So all parent nodes will have an active state.

Therefore, I don't now of a pure CSS solution. You can avoid a javascript solution (which I assume is what you're really after), by altering the markup so that the div that has an active state is no longer a parent of the button. You can make them siblings, for example.

The CSS part of that solution is then fixing the layout so it appears the same now that they are sibilings as what it did when they were parent>child.

Without seeing a fiddle of what you're working with, I can't offer you a more specific solution I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

try this

html:

```
<div class="current" id="current">
  <button id="btnclick" >Qlick me</button>
</div>
```

css script:

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.current_active{
  background-color: red;
}
```

jquery:

```
$("#btnclick").click(function(){
    $("#current").toggleClass("current_active");
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s0at4w4b/17/)

ps: include the jquery library file

Answer (score 0):

The :active pseudo-class applies while an element is being activated by the user. For example, between the times the user presses the mouse button and releases it. On systems with more than one mouse button, :active applies only to the primary or primary activation button (typically the "left" mouse button), and any aliases thereof.

There may be document language or implementation specific limits on which elements can become :active. For example, [HTML5] defines a list of activatable elements.

**The parent of an element that matches :active also matches :active.**
**So there,s no way**

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to any CSS way to handle this case. (not sure about CSS4, the way Amit has suggested.) So here is JQuery way.

The idea is you handle mousedown and mouseup events at 3 levels:

1. the parent div
2. the button where you don't want the active state propagated to parent div (".btn1" in the example below)
3. any other children except the button in second condition. (".btn2" in the example below)

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s0at4w4b/20/)

HTML:

```
<div>
  <button class="btn1">Qlick me1</button>
  <button class="btn2">Qlick me2</button>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('div').each(function(e){
        $(this).mousedown(function(e){
            $(this).addClass("activeClass");
        }).mouseup(function(e){
            $(this).removeClass("activeClass");
        });
    });
    $('div .btn1').each(function(e){
        $(this).mousedown(function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
        }).mouseup(function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
    $('div :not(.btn1)').each(function(e){
        $(this).mousedown(function(e){
            $(this).parent().addClass("activeClass");
        }).mouseup(function(e){
            $(this).parent().removeClass("activeClass");
        });
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.activeClass {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS pseudo-elements are incredibly useful -- they allow us to create CSS triangles for tooltips and perform a number of other simple tasks while preventing the need for additional HTML elements.  To this point, these pseudo-element CSS properties have been unreachable by JavaScript but now there's a method for getting them!

Check this:

http://davidwalsh.name/pseudo-element

http://davidwalsh.name/ways-css-javascript-interact